# Is 帰る correct in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, translation, word-choice, words

> ハンダは魔女たちの言葉を覚えて、川べりへ帰りました。

Is 帰る correct in this sentence? ハンダ is a name of my character.

Can I say 川べりへ using へ?

I wanted to write: Handa remembered witches spell and then go back to the river shore.

Comment: 「ハンダは魔女たちの言葉を覚えて」じゃなくて「ハンダは魔女たちの言葉を思い出して」じゃないですかね・・　覚える would be more like "memorize".

Comment: ハンダは魔女たちの言葉を暗記して、川べりへ戻りました。sounds better?

Comment: Oh, so you really meant to say "Handa **memorized** the witches' spell and then went back to the riverbank." rather than "Hand recalled..."

Comment: use, so my sentence is correct? ハンダは魔女たちの言葉を暗記して、川べりへ戻りました this way?

Comment: So the 魔女 just told the spell to ハンダ and ハンダ memorized the spell.「魔女たちの[呪文]{じゅもん}を覚えて、[川岸]{かわぎし}へ戻りました。」とかですかね・・・  覚える/暗記する is remember in the sense of "memorize / learn by heart", while 思い出す is "remember / recall"

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the context: 帰る is usually used when returning to one's own house/home/homeland, whereas 戻る is used when returning to a place that isn't those things.

Comment: So, if I say ハンダは魔女たちの言葉を覚えて、川べりへ戻りました。it sounds perfectly normal?

or ハンダは魔女たちの言葉を暗記して、川べりへ戻りました。sounds better?

Comment: As I said, it depends on the context of the narrative in your sentence. 戻る is normal if you are talking about returning to a previous location that isn't considered 'home'.